# Is java actually faster than C# in bubble sort?

Tags: java, c#, sorting, optimization

I wanted to check whether c# or java is faster with executing bubble sort function to sort 100000 unsorted records.

For C#, I used this code for bubble sort:

```
        static void sort(int[] table)
    {
        int n = table.Length;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                if (table[i] > table[i + 1])
                {
                    int tmp = table[i];
                    table[i] = table[i + 1];
                    table[i + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
            n--;
        }
        while (n > 1);
    }
```

For java, It's almost the same:

```
static void sort(int[] table)
    {
        int n = table.length;
        do
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            {
                if (table[i] > table[i + 1])
                {
                    int tmp = table[i];
                    table[i] = table[i + 1];
                    table[i + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
            n--;
        }
        while (n > 1);
    }
```

To measure execution time, in C# I used `Stopwatch` class:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            sort(arr);
            sw.Stop();
```

I couldn't find Stopwatch class in Java and I used this code to measure execution time in Java:

```
 class ExecutionTimer {
  private long start;
  private long end;

  public ExecutionTimer() {
    start = System.nanoTime();
  }

  public void end() {
    end = System.nanoTime();
  }

  public float duration(){
    return (end-start);
  }

  public void reset() {
    start = 0;  
    end   = 0;
  }}
```

I run algorithm 5 times in C# and 5 times in Java. The average time for execution time in C# was: **40,13s** , in JAVA was: **18,44s**.

Why the difference is so big? Is it because I used StopWatch to measure time in C#?
I had closed every program, browser and anti-virus on my laptop during the test.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you run the C# version with the debugger attached?

Comment: Did you compile the C# code in release mode?

Comment: I run it with debug mode.

Comment: Running a debug version is going to be slow. Running with the debugger attached (i.e. pressing F5 in Visual Studio) is going to be really slow. Run a release version without the debugger (press Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio, or select "Run without debugger"). If you're running a debug version or with the debugger attached, your times are going to be wildly off.

Answer (score 3):

I would not be surprised if C# runs slower than java, but the difference here is so big because your testing methodology is not up to snuff.

You cannot just invoke the code to be benchmarked sandwitched between clock readings.  You have to first allow the code to be jitted, by running it many times over.  In benchmarking circles, this is known as "warmup", and it is necessary for languages that are compiled into bytecode (or MSIL at the case may be) and then just-in-time-compiled during runtime.

How many times is enough to warm up?  Opinions differ; I have heard you have to run it once, I have heard you have to run it 10000 times.  Try and see what you get.

Comment: *"Jitted"* - Just in Time Compiled/Interpreted

Comment: Why do I have to 'warm up' ? I run C# code and Java code in the same conditions - without 'warm up', on the same pc, no background processes. Then, for me java is faster because it does not need warming to compiling it faster.

Comment: Because the just-in-time compilation is a huge variable that you do not have any control over, so you do not want it to affect your measurement times.  If not for anything else, then at least because a slower jitter may be slower because it produces faster code, but the faster code would be unfairly penalized if measured together with the overhead of the jitter.

Comment: @ElPolako Both Java and C# are used mainly in long-running processes and that's what they're optimized for. Without the warmup, you're measuring the speed of something neither of them is any good for. +++ So even if Java was 100 times faster, the result bears no relevance.